# Get Atom Editor to Identiy .m files as Matlab/Octave rather than Objective-C

Tags: atom-editor

I have installed the languages-matlab package for Atom. However, Atom recognizes .m files as Objective-C files by default. While I can select from the language options at the right bottom and manually set it to Octave/Matlab, I find it far from optimal to do it each and every time.

Is there a setting I can use to get Atom to recognize .m files as Matlab/Octave only by default? I don't think I will have to program in Objective-C for the foreseeable future.

OS: GNU/Linux - Ubuntu 14.04(LTS)
Octave version 3.8.1
Atom Editor version 0.176.0

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?  What version of Matlab/Octave more information the better the question is.

Comment: I am not using OSX. I don't see how the Matlab/Octave version will help with this question but here it is: Octave version 3.8.1, Atom Editor version 0.176.0

Comment: So what are you using?  Update your question.

Comment: Have updated the question with details.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are working on the most recent version of Atom. In the same bottom-right menu that you are using to choose Matlab/Octave, there is now an auto detect feature

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should install [language-matlab-octave](https://atom.io/packages/language-matlab) plugin.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, does "language-matlab-octave plugin" answer the question "Is there a setting I can use to get Atom to recognize .m files as Matlab/Octave only by default?" with so reediting and more detail you could explain how this would fit the answer to the question.